# Husqvarna Leaf Blower running erratic

Tags: powertools

I put new carb, fuel line, filter and plug and it is still not running right.  The model is 125v.  Listen to the video.  It sounds like it is missing.https://youtu.be/JOWy6WD3uWY

Comment: Questions that require viewing a video are not generally a good fit for the Stack Exchange network. Also, small-engine questions are generally better handled on the mechanics.stackexchange.com site. Outdoor power equipment would be more on-topic on the gardening.stackexchange.com site in any case, but while you could get an answer either there or here, the engine-specific site is really the only place this question would be on-topic.